# Javascript diashow (picture array) with start/stop button not working, error: src is undefined

Tags: javascript, arrays, setinterval

When I start the diashow this is what I get: `Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'src' of undefined` Pointing to `function`: `runPicGal` (see below). Hope you can help. Note: The strange thing is that I see the picture changing ONE time then I get the error.

Full JS File:

```
var picForDiashow;
var diashowPicArray = [];
var diashowPicArrayIndex = 0;

diashowPicArray [0] = new Image(); diashowPicArray [0].src = "./pics/1.jpg";
diashowPicArray [1] = new Image(); diashowPicArray [0].src = "./pics/2.jpg";
diashowPicArray [2] = new Image(); diashowPicArray [0].src = "./pics/3.jpg";
diashowPicArray [3] = new Image(); diashowPicArray [0].src = "./pics/4.jpg";
diashowPicArray [4] = new Image(); diashowPicArray [0].src = "./pics/5.jpg";



function initForDiashow () {

    picForDiashow = document.getElementById("diashowPic");
}

window.onload = initForDiashow;





function startDiashow () {

    picInterval = window.setInterval(runPicGal, 1000);
}





function stopDiashow () {

    window.clearInterval(picInterval);
}




function runPicGal () {

    diashowPicArrayIndex++;

    if (diashowPicArrayIndex > diashowPicArray.length) {
        diashowPicArrayIndex = 0;
    } 
    picForDiashow.src = diashowPicArray[diashowPicArrayIndex].src;

}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are always adding the elements to the *first* position of the array. Thus, only the first element, `diashowPicArray[0]`, will be accessible. Change the initialization to the following:

```
diashowPicArray [0] = new Image(); diashowPicArray [0].src = "./pics/1.jpg";
diashowPicArray [1] = new Image(); diashowPicArray [1].src = "./pics/2.jpg";
diashowPicArray [2] = new Image(); diashowPicArray [2].src = "./pics/3.jpg";
diashowPicArray [3] = new Image(); diashowPicArray [3].src = "./pics/4.jpg";
diashowPicArray [4] = new Image(); diashowPicArray [4].src = "./pics/5.jpg";
```

Also, in your comparison, you should not use `diashowPicArrayIndex > diashowPicArray.length`. Otherwise, you'll try to access `diashowPicArray[5]`, which is out of bounds. Use `==` instead:

```
diashowPicArrayIndex++;
if (diashowPicArrayIndex == diashowPicArray.length) {
    diashowPicArrayIndex = 0;
}
```

Or, simplifying the above lines, using modular arithmetic:

```
diashowPicArrayIndex = (diashowPicArrayIndex + 1) % diashowPicArray.length;
```

Comment: Sorry for that, you are right of course. Now I see the diashow running but I get this error again when diashow has reached end of array and starts at 0 again. Why?

Comment: You should have `diashowPicArrayIndex == diashowPicArray.length` instead. Otherwise, you'll try to access the array in the `length` position, which doesn't exist, since arrays are 0-indexed.